# could not form a regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to form a regex which matches the file name from the path.

Here is the example of my url
"../assets/sounds/toucObsSound_.mp3"

and here is my regex
`\b[^/]\w+[^.]`

What is wrong with this? it matches all the character like
assets
sounds
touchObsSound

Regex Explanation

neglect the / and match everything till you find . and neglect the .

I think I am doing a mistake here. Someone please help?

Comment: That looks like a path, not a URL. Why are you using regex for this anyway?

Comment: Add a language tag. It's important.

Comment: Yeap sorry that was a mistake,it is a path. I just want `touchObsSound` the file name without the extension

Comment: Maybe [`[^\/.]+(?=\.[^\/]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/BEgzP9/1) will do.

Comment: Also, `[^...]` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Wilktor's got this, also that website is a life saver for regex... www.regex101.com

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```
[^\/.]+(?=\.[^\/]*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BEgzP9/1) (note that `/` does not always have to be escaped, it depends on where you use the regex and how).

**Details**

- `[^\/.]+` - a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches 1 or more chars other than `/` and `.`
- `(?=\.[^\/]*$)` - a [**positive lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that requires a `.` and then 0+ chars other than `/` up to the end of the string (`$`) immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
/([^./]+)\.mp3$
```

It'll match what is between the last / and .mp3 at the end of the line.  In this case that is what you have asked for: toucObsSound_

Here is a good way to play around with it to tweak as needed:

https://regex101.com/r/Er6kGQ/1

If you need to remove the _ you can use this:

```
/([^./]+)\_.mp3$
```

Comment: Can you explain?